# Is there C# code to invoke the null-check feature of `brtrue`/`brfalse` instruction directly on an object reference?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, opcode

If the title makes sense, please skip below to my **Questions** section. If not, here's some context.

I am writing some code, and it happened to use the null-coalescing operator.
My code:

```
_handle = handle ?? throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof(handle));
```

Both `_handle` and `handle` are of type `class Handle` (that I've written).

I decided to investigate the IL. Here's what it spits out:

```
...
IL_0002: ldarg.1      // handle
IL_0003: dup          
IL_0004: brtrue.s     IL_0012   // transfer to line that stores into _handle
IL_0006: pop          
IL_0007: ldstr        "handle"
IL_000c: newobj       instance void [mscorlib]System.ArgumentNullException::.ctor(string)
IL_0011: throw        
IL_0012: stfld        class Sandbox.V1.Handle Sandbox.V1.Spade::_handle
...
```

I see here that the `brtrue.s` (or it could've been a `brfalse.s` with slightly different code) instruction (IL_0004) doesn't really check that the `handle` reference equals (or not) null (`ldnull`).
Instead it calls `brfalse` directly on the `handle` reference.

In other words, it did not do something along the lines of this at the beginning:

```
...
IL_0001: ldarg.1      // handle
IL_0002: ldnull       
IL_0003: ceq          
IL_0004: brfalse.s    IL_0012   // transfer to line that stores into _handle
...
```

Of course, there would be more IL code generated with the second approach, but for the purpose of this question, I only typed the relevant part.

**Questions:**
1) Would there be any measurable difference between the two approaches?
The first approach (which is what the compiler does with my C# code above) calls `brtrue/false)` directly on the object reference, whereas the second approach calls `brtrue/false` on the result of comparison of the object with `ldnull` (which is what the compiler generates with `== null` checks).
From what I understand, the first approach processes at least one less instruction, so at some level, this is measurable.
2) If so, is there a way to force the compiler to generate such IL for null-checks in C#?
i.e. write an equivalent of `myObj != null` in C#, where the generated IL calls `brtrue.s` directly on `myObj` reference.

Or am I missing something fundamental? IL isn't my strongest suit.
I am also open to someone reasonably convincing me that I'm just being crazy here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you test what it produces for a regular if-statement?

Comment: IL is only half way to execution. I think stuff like that will probably optimized by the JIT. You should compare that too.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If you mean something like `if (obj == null)`, yes, I've tested that. Depending on whether it's `==` or `!=` it does a `ceq` or `cgt_un` against `ldnull` and then the `br...`. So basically, the second approach in my post above.

Comment: @thehennyy Good point. I'll try and give that a shot.

Comment: Also remember to look at debug aswell as release code.

Comment: Both methods are jitted to the same asm (excuse the formatting, typed on my phone) : https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFAJiQGEkBvHJapABwCcBLANzGAFNSkB9AYy2w0UBOABYkAWQAUZXgEoKVITT4BeXgH4NSYAAt6AewDuSAHbsTAUQAevdrWCMDpqQoFCAvkuo58KcRKEMkjyioI0jABmSFK8qqqmAK4ANskK3so6+sZmFkg2dg5OLm4ZavwZXuFIHkhAA==

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 the generated IL is already essentially the same (`brtrue.s`). The problem here is that the OP is worrying about micro optimizations analyzing the output of a debug build...

Comment: No, any such differences in the generated IL would disappear once the just-in-time compiler generates and optimizes the machine code for it.  The processor has only one optimal way to do it.  You are simply seeing the operator??() code generator take advantage of IL features, micro-optimizing IL to make it as compact as possible is strongly pursued in the compiler and the metadata interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking at a debug build. If you are worrying about micro optimizations, looking at a  build with optimizations turned off is nonsensical.

In a release build, `handle == null` will also make use of `btrue.s`. On a debug build however, the generated IL will be as close as possible to the actual C# code in order to achieve a good debugging experience.

The following code:

```
public void M(object o) {
    if (o == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(); }
```

In Release mode will output the following IL:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1
IL_0001: brtrue.s IL_0009
IL_0003: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.ArgumentException::.ctor()
IL_0008: throw
IL_0009: ret
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, IL is only part-way towards what actually runs when the code is executed. So, with regards the first part of your question, the fact that the `ldnull`/`ceq` version is longer will naturally mean it takes *very slightly* longer to load it into memory, and it's more instructions for the JIT to analyze and compile to native code.

These differences are however essentially negligible given how slight the difference is, and since they are one-off activities, are effectively irrelevant to the performance of the JIT-ted method when it actually runs. For that we'd need to see what instructions are actually generated when the method is JIT-ted and if there's any difference.

To this end, I put together two dynamic methods, emitting the desired IL explicitly, and checked what native code the JIT generated for the two versions.

The results were perhaps unsurprisingly identical (specifically, a `test XXX,XXX` followed by a `je ...`), so clearly the JIT has the ability to recognize these patterns of IL and treats them the same way when emitting native code.

For the second part of your question, as the [answer from InBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229737/is-there-c-sharp-code-to-invoke-the-null-check-feature-of-brtrue-brfalse-ins/51230465#51230465) indicates, once compiled in Release mode, the differences between the generated IL disappear, and both use the shorter `brfalse`/`brtrue` approach.

Comment: In release mode the generated IL in both cases is the same. Jitter doesn't come into play here.

Comment: @InBetween The question asks whether there's "any measurable difference between the two approaches", which I took to mean "at the IL level". It therefore makes sense to analyze the difference between the different forms of the null check, and whether there's any impact to the JIT-ted code.

Comment: But the question is based on a false belief. Both null checks output the same IL in Release mode (both make use of  `brtrue.s`). As I state in  my answer, worrying about micro optimizations when you are building a debug build is nonsensical to begin with. The Jitter doesn't need to optimize anything here, the optimized IL is already the same.

Comment: @InBetween I fail to see the false belief - the asker has made an observation, and has quite reasonably asked for an explanation of the differences, and I'd commend the asker on their curiosity, and interest in furthering their understanding and knowledge. To take the view that this is a worthless micro-optimization and they are wasting their time would seem to miss the point entirely.

Comment: The false belief is that the compiler generates different IL for `??` and `==  null`. It *doesn't*, both will use `brtrue.s`. The observed difference is only true in *debug builds*. Talking about jitter optimizations in a debug build doesn't make sense; by definition its a non optimized build to begin with.